# Oracle Applications Concurrent Manager Job Owner

Tags: oracle, concurrency, owner, oracleapplications

By default concurrent manager jobs are run under the APPS user.  Is it possible to configure it to run as another user?  I'd like to be able to isolate some of my stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any standard way, but you could code your concurrent request to handle that. E.g. copy fnd_concurrent_requests, then in the "real" concurrent program insert into your custom_fnd_concurrent_requests "select * from fnd_concurrent_requests". Create dbms_job or something to poll your custom table, and get it to call your "real" program - make sure you fnd_global.initialize with the user, resp, and appl from fnd_concurrent_requests, and direct output to your own files using utl_file rather than fnd_file.